# How to use regex to match ASTERISK in awk

Tags: regex, awk

I'm stil pretty new to regular expression and just started learning to use awk. What I am trying to accomplish is writing a ksh script to read-in lines from text, and and for every lines that match the following:

*RECORD     0000001     [some_serial_#]

to replace $2 (i.e. 000001) with a different number. So essentially the script read in batch record dump, and replace the record number with date+record#, and write to separate file.

So this is what I'm thinking the format should be:

```
awk 'match($0,"/*RECORD")!=0{$2="$DATE-n++"; print $0} match($0,"/*RECORD")==0{print $0}' $BATCH > $OUTPUT
```

but obviously "/*RECORD" is not going to work, and I'm not sure if changing $2 and then write the whole line is the correct way to do this. So I am in need of some serious enlightenment.

Comment: Where does "FTR" come from? Do you want "$DATE" literally or to substitute a date? Is "n++" literal or do you want to increment a variable?

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited the original post now. That code was originally for another scripts, that I forgotten to change the VAR. $DATE is a variable I will define in script, and n++ just incremental var, starting from where I define earlier in the script, which omitted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want your example line to look like

```
*RECORD $DATE-n++ [some_serial_#]
```

after awk's done with it?

```
awk '{ if (match($0, "*RECORD") != 0) { $2="$DATE-n++"; }; print }' $BATCH > $OUTPUT
```

---

Based on your update, it looks like you instead expect `$DATE` to be an environment variable which is used in the awk expression and `n` is a variable in the awk script that keeps count of how many records matched the pattern.  Given that, this may look more like what you want.

```
$ cat script.awk
BEGIN { n=0 }
{
    if (match($0, "\*RECORD") != 0) {
        n++;
        $2 = (ENVIRON["DATE"] "-" n);
    }
    print;
}

$ awk -f script.awk $BATCH > $OUTPUT
```

Comment: I must've not getting it quite right... I got this erroutput
"awk: 0602-521 There is a regular expression error./n
        ?*+ not preceded by valid expression./n
/n
 The source line number is 1./n
 The error context is/n
                { if (match($0, >>>  "*FTR") <<</n

Comment: Then your awk needs the `*` to be escaped -- `match($0 "\\*RECORD")`.  Mine was the opposite and gave a warning that I was needlessly escaping the `*`.

Comment: No matter how I tried I just can't get it right: The error context is { if (match($0, >>>  "\*RECORD") <<<

Comment: In the end I discarded match() and used binary conditional for the matching.... match() would not let me escape the Asterisk right... awk '{if ($1 == "\*RECORD"){$2="$DATE-$SEQ"};{print $0}}'

Answer (score 0):

use equality.

```
D=$(date +%Y%m%d)
awk -vdate="$D" '
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
   if ( $i == "*RECORD" ){
      $(i+1) = date"00002"
      break # break after searching for one record, otherwise, remove break
   }
  }
}1' file
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, after a few tweaks on my own, I finally got it to do what I needed!